# Online Collaborative Schema Design (leverage google docs?)

Tags: sql, schema, database-schema, google-docs

I'm looking for an online, collaborative database schema designer.  App is for MySQL specifically, but generic DB designer is fine too.
It's important that it can handle revisions (history of changes).

This looks cool, and I could host it on a server - but doesn't look like it would handle multi-user:
http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Currently we're doing a lot of design collaboration on google docs/spreadsheets.  Has anyone had any success using google spreadsheet for schema design?  Even if there were just a gadget for drawing lines/connections, I might give Google Docs a shot.

Comment: +1 for a good question.  Some (most?) projects begin with database design so this would be useful.

Comment: Do you think this question should also be tagged "schema-design" and, possibly, "database-design"?

Answer (score 1):

You could represent the database schema using UML, which brings up a different question: is there any collaboration software out there for building UML diagrams?  SAP had some software built on Google Wave to do some UML-like, collaborative editing (theirs was to model processes I think) but I'm not sure where it went when Google Wave flopped.  I think it is now StreamWork (http://www.sapstreamwork.com/how-it-works).  I didn't see any diagramming tools there.

Comment: StreamWork is still going strong, but it has never had any special support for UML or scheme design.  It should be possible to write a custom business method for those cases, but as far as I know none exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) let's you play with DB design using a web interface.
How cool is that

Answer (score 0):

Check https://dbhub.io/, which allows to host sqlite database to be shared online. Users can mark whether the database is public or private.

Source code can be found on https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/dbhub.io